# FileOutputStream Java Error

Tags: java, filenotfoundexception, read-write

I have a strange error in Java trying to output some data. I have read and write access to the file. The file exists (`yourFile.exists()` prints `True`) but still I get the `Java.io.FileNotFoundException`.

Sample code:

```
File yourFile = new File("./output/blah.txt");
FileOutputStream oFile = new FileOutputStream(yourFile);
```

Anyone knows anything I can try to fix this?

Comment: In what line of code do you get the exception?

Comment: When asking about an exception, always post the complete stack trace of the exception.

Comment: @The_Programmer: the second one. yourFile.exists() prints "True", yourFile.getAbsolutePath() gives "./output/blah.txt" and access rights for the file are read&write for everyone... So i'm a bit puzzled :)
JB Nizet: I'm not sure how to do this?

Comment: can you also put the File locations to the question, (Your `Java Class File` and the `Input file`)

Comment: Could it be a secundary error: oFile not being closed, so still open, when a second time the same file is opened?

Comment: It indeed has something to do with the file not being closed I think. I've currently noticed that he doesn't give the error when I put my code in a try{ }-block while it still executes it and is able to write to this file. I don't quite get why it doesn't work without a try-block, but for now my problem is solved. Do you see any reason?

Answer (score 1):

Beware that `FileOutputStream`'s constructor can throw a `FileNotFoundException` for several different causes:

`FileNotFoundException` - *if the file exists but is a directory rather than a regular file, does not exist but cannot be created, or cannot be opened for any other reason*.

Comment: Yes I've checked several options: 
- yourFile.exists() prints "True" 
- yourFile.getAbsolutePath() gives "./output/blah.txt" (so not a directory)
- Access rights for this file are set to "Read/Write: Everyone"

Comment: An absolute path should not start with `./`?

Comment: Are you sure it is not a directory?  Your test "yourFile.getAbsolutePath() gives "./output/blah.txt" (so not a directory)" does not prove it is not a directory. Can you please show us an "`ls -l ./output/blah.txt`"?

Comment: this is the output: 
-rw-r--r--  1 Putseys  staff  0 Jan 22 13:48 ./output/blah.txt
but i found out it does work in a try{}-block, i.e. it is able to write to this file if i put all my code in a try-block. So my problem is solved, but I'm clueless why (not so experienced with Java); do you have an idea?

Comment: Where you getting the exception at runtime, or a compile-time warning that you were not catching a checked exception?? 

Can you show us the error you were getting?